# QWebEngineView & API access token fetching

Tags: c++, qt, oauth

Basically I'm just messing around with a library which should work with some API (for studying purpose). So, in order to conform OAuth protocol I need to authorize using some sort of web view and get access token. AT is passed as GET parameter after redirection. As a novice in Qt, I have no idea how to track web view state and fetch essential data.

Practically I have an auth procedure that takes a callback, which has to return access token afterwards, as a parameter.

```
vk_api::auth<>("123456", vk_api::scopes::friends, [this](const std::string& contents) -> std::string {
    this->ui->m_webview->setHtml(QString(contents.c_str()));
    ...
});
```

Also, I do not want to block UI while calling it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some options you have:

1. Use the new [Qt Network Authorization](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetworkauth-index.html) library.
2. If you want to do it yourself, the usual way is to let the service redirect to a localhost port, which you listen to. See [QTcpServer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcpserver.html) and [Network Programming with Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-programming.html) for that.
3. Qt WebKit is deprecated, use [QWebEngineView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview.html) instead. You can intercept requests and look for the authorization token using a [QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineurlrequestinterceptor.html)
4. You can intercept requests made from Qt WebKit and look for the authorization by using a custom [QNetworkAccessManager](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html).

Comment: QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor actually did the thing. Appreciate your help.